# Timer on server side in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timer, background

What am trying to achieve is:
1. User pressess button and starts time-limited form.
2. Timer starts.
3. After X time when timer reaches 0 and user did not finish the form, rails create a record in database and do some session cleaning actions (Model.create and session.delete).

This timer will work like safety measure if user starts the form and then becomes unavailable (closes web brower or shuts PC).

Could you point to me to right direction? Where I should start? What language/framework should I use to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamps to record when something happened. Rails already has a great example of this in the `updated_at` and `created_at` fields.

You can re-use this concept to store when the user first started filling out the form, perhaps on the resource's `new` route, which usually coincides with the opening of the form.

As for performing the cleanup, you have two options that would could even both work together, depending on the situation:

1. If the cleanup isn't security-sensitive, you could have a timer kick off on the front-end and then send an AJAX request to the back-end when it expires.
2. If the cleanup isn't time-sensitive, you could [run a task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks) every few minutes or so, which performs the cleanup on any forms that haven't been cleaned up yet. It would look at the timestamps to determine this.

Aside from those suggestions, we'd have to know more about your use cases to answer more questions.

1. Is the cleanup time-sensitive?
2. Is the cleanup security-sensitive?

There are more options - you could run the task more granularly or more securely.

### Tight timing

One option if your timing is very tight (down to seconds) is to implement both options above, and in addition the following functionality:

1. Use ActionCable to keep a web socket open with the user. Periodically have them ping the server to check their status.
2. In a `before_filter`, probably in `ApplicationController`, check first if they have permission to continue the action, i.e. the timestamp hasn't expired yet. If the timestamp has expired, and the cleanup hasn't been performed yet, then perform it now.

Limitations of this approach:

1. If the user closes the website entirely, the cleanup is not going to happen until the next cleanup task happens.
2. There are vulnerabilities on the front-end. The user can disable the front-end checks, and then avoid submitting the form, which will delay the cleanup in the same way as #1.

Comment: It is time sensitive. User has exactly X number of minutes and then rails create a record. The thing is, it has to run even when user is not there, so  I have to rely on server-side timer. Think about it like quiz with time limit. User starts it and have 15 minute to finish it, otherwise he gets 0. If he leaves PC (or turns off web browser) or forget to submit the form in these 15 minutes, he gets 0.

Comment: How time-sensitive? Is a margin of 5 minutes acceptable? 1 minute? Or are we talking seconds?

Comment: Seconds, it should be as close to planned time as it can.

Comment: I added an additional option in the answer above. Please read and tell me what you think.